# Drupal prints unwanted characters

Tags: drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal, I'm getting unwanted characters printed on the website. After header, I get h character, and f after footer, and w after widget. How can I remove this?

This is an example of header code, note the h character there:
http://prntscr.com/k15afh there are also w and f characters after widgets and footer.

Note, I'm using Drupal 7

Comment: Please provide some more details and/or code if you created.

Comment: Can you please check your `page.tpl.php` file and/or `page--front.tpl.php` and/or `node.tpl.php` file and FIND using editor for such characters? This can not be an issue from Drupal's end. Let us know what you find.

Comment: this is the content of page.tpl.php inf sites/all/themes/theme/templates: <header role="banner" id="page-header">
    <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
</header> <!-- /#page-header --> where can I find the page: header?

Comment: `header` is not a page. Its a region. Your screenshot does not exist on the URL anymore but I would suggest that you make a project wide search for unwanted "h" "f" and "w" characters. Make sure that you have selected find by word radio button. This is surely custom thing and it can not be a Drupal issue.

Comment: thank you, but how can I edit the header region? maybe these characters are there. Because when searching I get hundreds of results.

Comment: You might not have searched for "Find by word". And header region consists of blocks. You can check those blocks at Admin >> Structure >> Block.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line in the custom blocks module:

$block['content'] = array('data' => array('#theme' => 'header_view', '#node' => $node,),'class' => array('header_view'),);
return $block;

It was returning h character (as the first character of header_view) as a result of using class the. I don't know if this is an obsolete method, or it's a code mistake.